# How do I exit a python script using a hotkey like ctrl+q?

Tags: python, automation, keypress

I've only just picked up python and am trying to make scripts that can do menial labor but would like a custom hotkey to exit the code.
Please excuse any jank, I am new to coding and have just copied other stack overflow answers.

```
def theFunction():
    
    color = (255, 255, 255)

    s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(386, 847, 300, 400))
    if s.getpixel((0, 0)) == color:
        pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, duration = 1)  # do something here
        return
    
    print("a")
    print("b")

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+q'):
        print("You pressed 'a'.")
        break
    time.sleep(0.1)
    theFunction()
```

The script will move my mouse somewhere if the color of a pixel is pure white.
What I have found out with this is that if it detects pure white, then I am unable to exit the code because it is too busy moving my mouse. So I encased it in a function to break out of the if statement and added a sleep command so that it would give me some time to use ctrl+q to stop the code, but the time window isn't long enough and I would like to make it as small as possible.
What I would like is a way to exit the script while it is executing the automation commands.

Comment: You could use multi-threading. In one thread you run the loop that checks for the hot-key, and calls `sys.exit()` when it's detected. The other thread does the automation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use another thread for `the_function`:

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import multiprocessing


def the_function():
    while True:
        print('Doing something...')
        s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(386, 847, 300, 400))
        if s.getpixel((0, 0)) == (255, 255, 255):
            pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, duration=1)
            return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=the_function)
    p.start()
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+q'):
            p.terminate()
            print('Process stopped...')
            break
```

Comment: i really like this answer...  the only comment is to create a `main()` function and call that from the global scope...